# subprocess.call nohup & - doesn't run process in background

Tags: python, django, bash, scrapy, subprocess

I have a function (Django admin) that runs Scrapy spider. The function works correctly. What I'm trying to do now is to make it non-blocking.

This works as expected - I need to wait for the finish of SH SCRIPT. So basically I click on this action and browser is waiting for the end of crawling.

```
subprocess.call([settings.CRAWL_SH_ABS_PATH, "db_profiles_spider", "ids", ids])
```

I want it to be non-blocking so the browser refreshes immediately.

I tried this:

```
subprocess.call(["nohup",settings.CRAWL_SH_ABS_PATH, "db_profiles_spider", "ids", ids, '&'])
```

But it seems to be blocking and browser waits for the response. Why? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is for shell so try like this:

```
cmd = ' '.join(["nohup", settings.CRAWL_SH_ABS_PATH, "db_profiles_spider",
                "ids", ids, '&'])
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

#### UPDATE:

For me it also works without using `nohup`.

You can also create a thread and run the command in that thread. It's also ok to `os.fork()` and run the command in the child process.

Comment: just tried and `subprocess.call([...], shell=True)` does not work. the command needs to be a string.

Comment: From my understanding, the `nohup` ensures that the output from the background process continues to be collected, even if the parente process does not live anymore.

Comment: it makes more sense when a pty is involved so the process will be immune to SIGHUP.

Comment: for example, according to bash manual, "The shell exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP. Before exiting, an interactive shell resends the SIGHUP to all jobs, running or stopped. Stopped jobs are sent SIGCONT to ensure that they receive the SIGHUP." you can try like this: use putty to ssh to a sever (suppose remote shell is bash) and run `sleep 9999 &`, then force close the putty window. bash will receive SIGHUP and it'll send SIGHUP to the sleep process and sleep will be killed.